# How to validate a required Title fieldset with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to validate a dropdown menu with titles (such as Mr, Mrs, Ms..) and I need this to be a required field and display an error message if a title is not chosen.

I was able to validate all the other fields (which are inputs) by using their name atribute in the rules section of jquery and display the messages i want.

But for the title field, the name atribute does not work as it does for the inputs and I can't find a solution for it.

Any insight on how to solve this?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="diabetestool.css">
    <title>Zedland Health Authority diabetes tool Contact form</title>
</head>
<body>
       <header>
            <h1>Zedland Health Authority<br>Contact Us</h1>
        </header>
        <main >
            <form id="contactForm">
                <div id="left">
                    <fieldset id="title_field">
                        <label for="title">Title*</label>
                        <p class="donotdisplay" id="titleMessage">Select a Title</p>
                        <select name="title" id="title">
                            <option value="-1">Please select your Title</option>
                            <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
                            <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
                            <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
                            <option value="miss">Miss</option>
                            <option value="master">Master</option>
                        </select> <span class="error">title</span>
                    </fieldset>
```

//

```
$(function() {
    $("#contactForm").validate ({

    rules: {
        title:{
            required: true,

        },
        fname: {
            lettersonly:true,
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
        },
        sname:{
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/i,
        },
        han:{
            required: true,
            pattern: /^ZHA\d{6}/,

        },

        email:{
            required: true,
            email: true,
        },

        tnumber:{
            required: false,
            pattern: /^[0-9]\d{10}/
        }

    },

    messages: {
        title:{
            required: "This field is required. Please select a title."

        },
        fname: {
          required: "This field is required. Please enter your first name.",
          lettersonly: "Please enter only letters." ,
          minlength: "First name must be at least two characters long." 

                },

        sname: {
          required: "This field is required. Please enter a valid Surname.",
          pattern: "Please enter a valid surname. Use only letters and if necessary, an hyphen (-).",
                },

        email:{
            required: "This field is required. Please enter a valid email address.",
        },

        han:{
            required: "This field is required. Please enter a valid Zedland Health Authority number.",
            pattern: "Your ZHA number should contain the characters ZHA (case sensitive), followed by six digits.",

        },

        tnumber:{
             pattern: "Please a valid UK telephone number."
        },
    },

},



    )},
)
```

Comment: Maybe remove the value="-1" from the first option so required starts working on title?

Comment: please create jsFiddle what you have done.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7m1fq9kx/ here is the JsFiddle without changing anything in the code yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the "-1" value from your first option, that should solve your validation issue

```
<select name="title" id="title">
       <option value="">Please select your Title</option>
       <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
       <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
       <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
       <option value="miss">Miss</option>
       <option value="master">Master</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. Been stuck on this problem for way too long for a silly thing.

Answer (score 1):

*Just remove the -1 from value attribute.*

```
<option value="">Please select your Title</option>-->
```